# Azure Bot Message Extension auth is not responding

Tags: authentication, microsoft-teams, add-in

I have a message extension bot setup where you have to authenticate before you can use it. This has always worked previously but since a few days ago, when I click the sign in button sent from the compose extension, I just get Something went wrong, please try again. No pop-up opens, no logs, no other error.

This worked previously fine. I have the URL that opens in the valid domains, I have attached the return code. I have also attached the screenshot of the issue.

[image: This is the where I am facing the issue, after clicking on "Sign in" it is showing error -> Something went wrong]

When I click on "Sign in", no operation occurs for authentication. I have checked, the href is blank for "Sign in".

[image: This is the return code of the extension]

I have tried to get help from Microsoft, as they have updated the MS Teams application and some features are removed or changed but not provided me the solution yet.

Comment: Nadeem, kindly clarify if the href is blank for "Sign in" or any other character is visible in developer tool.

Comment: This is regarding third party authentication in MS Teams Add-in.

Comment: Similar issue has been reported here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/10208. Clicking on signin does nothing.